# Dialogflow V2: Attach user metadata with detect_intent

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Usecase: Using Dialogflow v2 APIs a text based chat bot is need to build for placing orders over SMS.

Sample incoming sms:

- I want to order 2 pairs of Product #1234
- Add 10 pairs of Product #22 to my cart

Each order is associated with the `phonenumber` and the `quality` of a `product`. So how to pass this `phonenumber` to the Dialogflow, detect intent api call, so it can be passed along with the fullfillment call, to finally make an api call to the backend server.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to attach any additional information you want to provide to fulfillment would be to send a [Context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-manage#set-rt) along with the request. Contexts can have their own parameters, so you would provide the additional information you want to send in these parameters. Your fulfillment can get the Context and the parameters set in it.